# Delete and refresh items from a listview and database

Tags: android

I cannot refresh my list view after deleting the records.

```
        String str3 = favtitle.get(position);
        //position = Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("id")));

                db.delete("Favorites7","title= '"+str3+"'",null);

                //mSchedule.notifyDataSetChanged();  
                cur.requery();

                cur= db.query("Favorites7", 
                        null, null, null, null, null, null);

                 cur.moveToFirst();
                  while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {

                        //name.append("n" + cur.getString(1));
                       //mylist.addAll(cur.getString(i));
                      favtitle.add(cur.getString(1));
                      favloc.add(cur.getString(3));
                      favemp.add(cur.getString(2));
                      lat.add(cur.getString(7));
                      log.add(cur.getString(8));
                                //nextScreenData.add(cur.getString(2).toString());
                        cur.moveToNext();
                    }


                    cur.close();

                    mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
                     HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                     for(int i=0;i<favtitle.size();i++)
                     {
                         map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                     map.put("train",favtitle.get(i));
                     map.put("value",favloc.get(i));
                     map.put("employer",favemp.get(i));

                     mylist.add(map);
                     }
                    mSchedule.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(Favorites.this, mylist, R.layout.listdelete,
                             new String[] {"train","value","employer"}, new int[] {R.id.dept,R.id.jobloc,R.id.employer});
                    lv.setAdapter(mSchedule);
                     lv.setDividerHeight(2);
                     lv.setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE);
                     //cur.requery();
```

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new Adapter, and then assign it to the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on your Adapter and it will reflect the changes to the ui

Answer (score 0):

When the delete button is clicked do the following:

1. Delete the corresponding list item from the database.
2. Get an new cursor for your list by executing the query which fills the list again.
3. Bind the new cursor to the list using [changeCurosr()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29).
4. Call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on the adapter.

Comment: i am able to delete items but it is not refreshing.....It is regenerating the list. When i go back and come again then it shows list with deleted items. I am doing this:

Comment: Mh, normally your code should work, although your concept to fill the list with data is a little bit weird. Why aren't you bind the cursor directly to the list using a SimpleCursorAdapter?